# simple SESSION management, do I have to use session_id, session_name for anything?

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables

I wrote a simple session routine (not fully tested yet) looks like it works properly.

```
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION["CREATED"])) 
    $_SESSION["CREATED"] = time();
  else if (time() > $_SESSION["CREATED"] + 10) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION["CREATED"] = time();
  };
  echo session_name() . "=" . session_id() . "<br>\n";
  print_r($_SESSION);
  echo "<br>\n";
// 6 possible cases: 
// 1, ["USER_ID"] present ...
  if (isset($_SESSION["USER_ID"])) {
// 1a, ... and ["LOGOUT"] present, logut required ...
    if (isset($_REQUEST["LOGOUT"])) {
      echo "user " . $_SESSION["USER_NAME"] . " logged out successfuly, good bye.\n";
      session_unset();
      session_destroy();
// 1b, ... and (["LAST_ACTIVITY"] not expired or ["NEVER_LOGOUT"] is true) ...
    } elseif ((isset($_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"]) && (time() < $_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"] + 5)) ||
       ((isset($_SESSION["NEVER_LOGOUT"]) && $_SESSION["NEVER_LOGOUT"]))) {
      echo "user " . $_SESSION["USER_NAME"] . " logged in, no further action needed\n";
      $_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"] = time();
// 1c, ... and ["LAST_ACTIVITY"] expired and no ["NEVER_LOGOUT"] ...
    } else {
      echo "user " . $_SESSION["USER_NAME"] . " logged in, session expired, login required\n";
      session_unset();
      session_destroy();
    };  
// 2, ... no ["USER_ID"] and no (["LOGIN_EMAIL"] or ["LOGIN_PASSWORD"]) ...
  } elseif (!isset($_REQUEST["LOGIN_EMAIL"]) || !isset($_REQUEST["LOGIN_PASSWORD"])) {
      echo "missing user and no login details, login required\n";
      session_unset(); // do i need these here?
      session_destroy();
// 3, ... no ["USER_ID"] and ["LOGIN_EMAIL"] and ["LOGIN_PASSWORD"] are present ...
  } else {
      echo "missing user, authentication needed (database)...\n";
// 3a, ... authenticated successfuly, logged in, happiness.
      if ($this->db_login($_REQUEST["LOGIN_EMAIL"], $_REQUEST["LOGIN_PASSWORD"], $userID, $userName)) {
        echo "... user $userName logged in, successful authentication";
        $_SESSION["USER_ID"] = $userID;
        $_SESSION["USER_NAME"] = $userName;
        $_SESSION["LAST_ACTIVITY"] = time();
        $_SESSION["NEVER_LOGOUT"] = isset($_REQUEST["LOGIN_NEVER_LOGOUT"]) && $_REQUEST["LOGIN_NEVER_LOGOUT"];
// 3b, ... authentication failed, user not exists or wrong details provided, retry.
      } else {
        echo "... authentication failed, provide correct login details (or leave me alone)";
      };
  };
```

Here is the db_login():

```
private function db_login($loginEmail, $loginPassword, &$userID, &$userName) {
  // no real DB access yet, dummy code, only for test purpose ...
  if ($loginEmail != "johnsmith@gmail.com")
    return false;
  $userID = 5;
  $userName = "John Smith";
  return true;
}
```

And the client HTML:

```
<form action="main.php" method="POST" id="login">
  <pre>e-mail:<input type="text" size=40 name="LOGIN_EMAIL" value="johnsmith@gmail.com"></pre>
  <pre>password:<input type="password" size=30 name="LOGIN_PASSWORD" value="johnsmith"></pre>
  <pre>never log out<input type="checkbox" name="LOGIN_NEVER_LOGOUT" value="true" checked></pre>
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

My questions are:
- What are the session_id, session_name for?
 
- Should I use them on any way?
- What is the benefit of them?
- Is there anything I should have done better or differently to make the code more safe?
Please let me know if I did something wrong in the code above. Although I have read few dozen articles, topics, I'm not fully understand the session's logic, so mistakes are very likely.

update: forgot to mention all the "echo" for test purpose only.

Comment: Why don't you read the manual? That will answer most of those questions for you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php. Also, you're regenerating your session id every 10 seconds, to me that is **major** overkill!!

Comment: I have read the manual, but I still not sure about the mentioned session functions, otherwise I wouldn't bother to post any question here. the 10 second is for test purpose only obviously.

Comment: I think even that 10 second wouldn't be problem because that code runs only when user interaction happens, which is not too often.